# osql -S not giving me expected results

Tags: java, sql, cmd, osql

I'm trying to write a program in Java that uses `osql` to generate a list of databases on a server. My code is as follows:

```
    public Object[] findDataBases(String server, String user, String passwd){
    str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "osql", " -S ", 
            server, " -U", user, "&&", "-P ", passwd, 
                            "&&", "sp_databases","&&", "GO"     
            };
    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    try{

        Process p = rt.exec(str);
        InputStream is = p.getInputStream();
        InputStream err = p.getErrorStream();
        InputStreamReader in = new InputStreamReader(is);
        InputStreamReader er = new InputStreamReader(err);

        BufferedReader buff = new BufferedReader(in);
        String line = buff.readLine();
        ArrayList<String> listDatabases = new ArrayList<String>();
        while (line != null){
            listDatabases.add(line.trim());
            /*for (int i = 0; i<4; i++){
                buff.readLine();
            }*/
            line =buff.readLine();
        }
        System.out.println("error stream:");
        buff = new BufferedReader(er);

        while ((line=buff.readLine()) != null){
            System.err.println(line);
        }

        databases = listDatabases.toArray();
        return databases;
    }
```

When I run this, for some reason I get a message as if I had run `osql -?`, which I obviously have not done.

I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks so much!

Comment: can you include the complete osql command (str) you are issuing? perhaps it is not being constructed as you intend.

Comment: I think it's in there - `str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "osql", " -S ", 
            server, " -U", user, "&&", "-P ", passwd, 
                            "&&", "sp_databases","&&", "GO"     
            };`
When I do it from the cmd prompt, it's:
`osql -S serverName -U userName -P password`

Comment: but how is that all concatenated together into a final command? what is with the `&&`s ?

Comment: Last time I tried using cmd.exe, I used the && to concatenate different commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

remove spaces from the arguments take && off: 
str = new String[] {"cmd.exe", "/c", "osql", "-S", server, "-U", user, "-P", passwd, "-Q", "sp_databases"};

Comment: I just tried this, and I got the following error: [SQL Native Client]Named Pipes Provider: Could not open a connection to SQL
Server [67].
[SQL Native Client]Login timeout expired
[SQL Native Client]An error has occurred while establishing a connection to
the server. When connecting to SQL Server 2005, this failure may be caused by
the fact that under the default settings SQL Server does not allow remote
connections.

Comment: which means the command line executed properly now but you have a problem with connection to your SQL server.
It would be much helpful if you post here the full command line as you run it from the command prompt.
Also try it first in the prompt and make sure it does the job.

Comment: It does do it in the command prompt - I tried it.  I think that after I used your code, the problem was with my server. Either I misspelled the name of the server in my variable, or there was an issue with the instance of it (\\ instead of / in a java string?). After I changed that, it worked. Thanks so much for your help.